# numpy isin issue for timestamps?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having a weird problem with the np.isin function. If I create a short pd.DatetimeIndex, and a date which exists within that index:

```
test_index = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2000-01-15',freq='B')
test_date = test_index[0]
```

I can check that the test_date is in fact the first element of the index:

```
test_date == test_index[0]
True
```

But the np.isin function seems to be unable to recognize test_date within test_index:

```
np.isin(test_index, test_date)
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
```

This occurs if I write this as

```
np.isin(test_index.values, test_date)
```

This seems wrong and weird. The data type of both test_date and test_index[0] is given as pd.Timestamp and there's no visible difference between them. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Not a bad question, and I see you've brought up a few recently on working with time series dates. It's always annoying to work with dates across these libs; part of the reason is because dates are generally difficult/take a long time to parse---but time series data generally tends to be, well, time-sensitive. So even though the special treatment of dates and times is frustrating compared to other numeric data, generally it is to your benefit to provide quick grouping, indexing, and so fourth. I tend to avoid the hassle as much as possible by strictly using epoch timestamps when I can.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds - thanks (and thanks for the answer below) - this is useful background information. I'll go and seek out some info on epoch timestamps because having potential errors like this lurking in my code makes me rather nervous.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `isin(test_date, test_index)`? That would be the normal order for a containment test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a numpy issue, it's a pandas issue. The problem is because `pd.date_range` creates a `DatetimeIndex`, which is a special type of index and stores the objects differently than what you get when you access them. From [the docs on `DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html#pandas-datetimeindex):

> Immutable ndarray of datetime64 data, represented internally as int64, and which can be boxed to Timestamp objects that are subclasses of datetime and carry metadata such as frequency information.

That is hard to parse. "Array of `type1` data, represented as `type2`, that gives you `type3` objects when you index."

I actually do *not* get the same type for each from Pandas; the type of the `test_date` is `pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp` for Pandas 0.22.0, which is in line with this documentation.

```
>>> test_index.dtype 
dtype('<M8[ns]')

>>> type(test_date)
pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp
```

As the docs state, this `Timestamp` has additional metadata, which does not convert well in numpy:

```
>>> np.array(test_date)
array(Timestamp('2000-01-03 00:00:00', freq='B'), dtype=object)
```

You can see I just got an object...that object is definitely not what is stored in the `DatetimeIndex`. This is what actually happens implicitly in numpy. From the [docs on `np.isin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) (in the Notes section):

> If test_elements is a set (or other non-sequence collection) it will be converted to an object array with one element.

So as we can see, the value is getting pushed into this `object` array, instead of a `datetime64` array, so you won't find your object in the `test_index` array.

The best bet is to use the built-in methods on a `DatetimeIndex` to search it, but you could also explicitly cast so numpy knows what's going on. Here are some different ways you could do this:

```
>>> np.isin(test_index, np.datetime64(test_date))
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False])
>>> test_index == test_date
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False])
>>> test_index.isin([test_date])
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False])
>>> test_index.contains(test_date) # if you just need yes or no
True
```